# Cannot open downloaded file from S3 with angular and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3

I´m trying to download an jpg image from amazon S3 using the NodeJs SDK. I´m able to get the file object on the backend. However when I try to create a blob object and download it from angular, I cannot open the file. When I try to open it with any image editor I get an error as if the file is damaged or incorrectly formatted.

Here´s my  Node JS code:

```
    function downloadFile(file,callback) {

      //Arranging file name
      var fileKey = file.lifeCycle + "/" + file.id + "." + file.extension;
      // download the file via aws s3 here
      console.log('Trying to download file', file.id);
      var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
      var s3 = new AWS.S3();
      var s3Params = {
        Bucket: 'myBucket',
        Key: fileKey
      };

/*
     res.attachment(fileKey);
     var fileStream = s3.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream();
     fileStream.pipe(res);
*/
      s3.getObject(s3Params, function (err, data) {

        if (err === null) {
          res.send(data);
        } else {
          res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        callback(null);

      });
    }
  });
```

The angular code:

```
vm.fileData = new ApiDownloadFile({fileId: 1});
vm.downloadFile = function(){
  console.log("Downloading...");

  vm.fileData.$query()
    .then(function(response){
      $log.log(response);
      window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder ||
        window.WebKitBlobBuilder ||
        window.MozBlobBuilder ||
        window.MSBlobBuilder;

      console.dir(response.headers);
      var blob = new Blob(response.Body.data,{type:response['content-type']});
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = "1.jpg";
      link.click();


    },function(err){
      $log.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: hmmm are you using IE or chrome? BlobBuilder is only supported by those two vendors according to mdn

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: Yes I solved it I´ll post an answer in a little while.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. The issue seemed to be with the Uint8 conversion.

I added this lines and it worked fine:

```
.then(function(response) {

  try{
    $log.log(response);
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(response.Body.data); // Convert the response to fix the problem of opening the file
    $log.log(arrayBufferView);
    var file = new Blob( [arrayBufferView], {type: response.ContentType});
```